# ASP.NET Dynamic Data Sorting on IDForeign Key

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-dynamic-data

In my application we are using ASP.NET Dynamic Data for data binding. Everything works fine.

If you see the code snipped below, it has Dynamic Field `DepartmentID` which is a foreign key to `Department` table and gets the department name from there (this is specified in `DynamicData/FieldTemplates/IDForeignKey.ascx.cs`).

Our requirement is to sort (order by) the records on the department name as they are visible on the grid view. The only option that I have is to sort on `DepartmentID` which does not serve our purpose.

How can we sort on data that is retrieved from ForeignKey?

### List.aspx

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridDataSource" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender"
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="EditHyperLink" runat="server"
                            NavigateUrl='<%# table.GetActionPath(PageAction.Edit, GetDataItem()) %>'
                        Text="Edit" />&nbsp;|&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                            CausesValidation="false" Text="Delete"
                            OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");'
                        />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="DepartmentID" HeaderText="Department" />                    
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"/>
            </Columns>

            <PagerStyle/>        
            <PagerTemplate>
                <asp:GridViewPager runat="server" />
            </PagerTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                There are currently no items in this table.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
        <asp:EntityDataSource OnSelecting="GridDataSource_Selecting" ID="GridDataSource"  runat="server" EnableDelete="true" OnDeleted="GridDataSource_Deleted"  >
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:DynamicControlParameter ControlID="DynamicFilter1" />
            </WhereParameters>
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not entirely clear from your question how are describe your metadata,
but anyway you can try to use **QueryExtender** control and **SearchExpression** class. More detail information you can find by link [QueryExtender and SearchExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.expressions.searchexpression.aspx) with examples.

The whole idea of this is use custom LINQ.